# Manipulating Cassandra writetime value

Tags: cassandra, ttl, nosql

Let's say I have an application, which receives periodically some measurement data.
I know the exact time the data was measured and i want every piece of data to be deleted in 30 days after it was measured.

I'm not inserting the data immediately to the database, but i want to use the time-to-live functionality of Cassandra.

Is there a way to manipulate the system intern time-stamp of a row in Cassandra so, that I can set time-to-live to 60 days, but it actually measures the lifespan of each row with my time-stamp?

E.g. I measure something at the 27.08.2014 - 19:00. I insert this data at 27.08.2014 - 20:00 into the database and set the time-to-live value to 1 day. I now want the row to be deleted at 28.08.2014 - **19:00** and not at 28.08.2014 - **20:00** like it normally would.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the folowing approach based on your example:

1. before insertion calculate Δx = insertTime - measureTime
2. set TTL = 1day - Δx for inserting row

**Addition on the basis of a comment:**

You can use [Astyanax](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki)-client with [Batch mutation](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Writing-data#batch-mutation) "to simultaneously enter multiple values at once". There is possibility to set TTL on each column and on whole row at once.

Comment: I would really like to not have this in the application itself(would be much easier). It's not clear yet, if it will ever be required to simultaneously enter multiple values at once. 
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html

Comment: @mkay, look at my updated answer. Other approaches to the calculation of TTL, unfortunately, can not offer.